# WIX- referring to the installation path from a custom action

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am writing a custom action (in c#) which runs on uninstall.

```
<Custom Action='My_CA' After='InstallInitialize'>Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
```

In my custom action I need to use API that is defined in a .dll which is in the installation folder, so I wrote this line:

```
[DllImport("myAPI.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

As you can see I tried to use only the dll name but the uninstall log says "Unable to load DLL 'myAPI.dll': The specified module could not be found". I figured I need to use a path relative to the install folder and not just the dll name, but I couldn't find the syntax of how to write it.
Can anyone tell me how to refer from c# custom action to the install folder?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined "execute" in your CA, the default is immediate meaning that it runs before any files are installed. You need an execute value of "deferred".

You also need it after the InstallFiles action so that the files are there.

Comment: I have defined execute in my custom action but I did not write this code section. Anyway, my "execute" is immediate because, as I wrote the CA should run on Uninstall. Before uninstalling all files are in the installation folder (on uninstall all files are already in the installation folder).